# Creating an array and skipping empty fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I have the following form:

```
                <input type="text" name="name1" id="names1" class="names" value="" placeholder="1) Name Here . . .">
                <input type="text" name="name2" id="names2" class="names" value="" placeholder="2) Name Here . . .">
                <input type="text" name="name3" id="names3" class="names" value="" placeholder="3) Name Here . . .">
                <input type="text" name="name4" id="names4" class="names" value="" placeholder="4) Name Here . . .">
```

I am trying to create an array when the user clicks the submit button that stores each name:

```
var values = $('.names').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
```

It works, but it also collects the empty fields which I do not need. I figure I require a conditional For statement for this, but I can't manage the syntax for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var values = $('.names').map(function() { if(this.value.trim() != '') return this.value; }).get();
```

Or:

```
var result = [];
var elements = getElementsByClassName('names');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    if(elements[i].value.trim() != '')
          result.push(elements[i].value);
}
```

Comment: Jesus. That was record response time. +5

Answer (score 0):

just select all .names with non empty value

```
var values = $('.names[value!=""]').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
```

in real world you will need to store names also:

```
var values = $('.names[value!=""]').map(function() { 
    return {name: this.name,value: this.value};
}).get();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/7ZcbY/